# Mono performance

Tags: performance, mono, runtime

Are there any performance benchmarks for Mono compared to say Java in GNU/Linux?

Have you ever tested Mono's performance?

Comment: Would anyone like to revisit this now that C# 4.0 is out?

Comment: @user482594 - I provided an up-to-date link in my answer that should stay current: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9138207/332026

Comment: @user482594 - The benchmarks game does show Mono 2.10.9, which does provide C# 4.0 -- but that doesn't mean that C# programs have been re-written to use C# 4.0 features.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an interesting post from Miguel on this.

> "Alvaro points out that in the
>   Language Shootout Benchmark Mono comes
>   in 18th place compared to Java's 10th
>   place.
>
> We know that Sun's proprietary Java
>   edition (not the open source one, as
>   that one is nowhere to be found yet)
>   is faster than Mono, but I was
>   surprised that we were so far behind.
>   So I looked at the comparison between
>   Java6 and Mono."

[image: Comparison - Java and Mono]
<sub>(source: [tirania.org](http://tirania.org/pictures/javavsmono.png))</sub>

[See Details Here](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2007/Dec-28.html)

Comment: That chart is way out of date! Here's one of the 4 current benchmarks game comparisons -- http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/csharp.php

Comment: @igouy That link doesn't load!

Comment: The machine hosting the storage for alioth.debian.org suffered catastrophic disk failure. http://lists.debian.org/debian-infrastructure-announce/2013/11/msg00001.html

Answer (score 29):

The latest version of this shoot-out can be found [here](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/csharp.php).

In a nutshell, compared to Java, Mono uses much less memory and runs a little slower.

To keep things in perspective, they both run about the same speed in the grand scheme of things. They both run these tests orders of magnitude faster than languages like Ruby, LUA, Python, PHP, and Perl. They are both in the same ball-park as Pascal, OCaml, Haskell, and LISP which makes them about half as fast as C and C++. Click [here](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php) for more detail.

To nitpick, we should be clear that our answers here compare Java and Mono C#. Both Mono and the JVM are environments targeted by various languages and the choice of language matters. For example, if we compare F# on Mono with Clojure on the JVM we get totally different results and suddenly "Mono" is "[faster](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=fsharp&lang2=clojure)".

While these comparisons are interesting and informative, you have to take them with a grain of salt. First, although some people do, most people writing Java and C# code are not running nothing but numerical algorithms in tight loops. Second, in some of these languages, the tested algorithms may just be calling into libraries that are written in C and not in the target language at all. Finally, other benchmarks (and implementations) would likely yield different results.

Still, it is reasonable to infer that Go is much faster than Ruby, C++ is faster than Go, and both Java and C# perform pretty reasonably given how productive they are (IMHO).

Answer (score 12):

amazedsaint > *There is an interesting post from Miguel on this.*

That chart is way out of date!

Here's [the current Mono C# 4.0 comparison](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/csharp.html)

Answer (score 2):

I [benchmarked Mono 2.2 against various other VMs including OCaml, LLVM, .NET and Java](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2009/01/mono-22.html):

[Mono 2.2 vs OCaml vs .NET vs LLVM vs JDK http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_NMRkpon4Ps0/SYNY8YtzTCI/AAAAAAAAACg/Bkjli4JV-NU/s1600-h/scimark2_individual.gif](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_NMRkpon4Ps0/SYNY8YtzTCI/AAAAAAAAACg/Bkjli4JV-NU/s1600-h/scimark2_individual.gif)

In summary, Mono 2.2 is better than Mono 2.0 but is still usually a *lot* slower than almost everything else.

Answer (score 2):

My benchmark (using complex mathematical problems and memory manipulation (with raw strings)):

MonoDevelop Windows (running on console using .net 3.5):
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 535
Realizando operações com strings longas... 2.038
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 530
Realizando operações com strings longas... 1.962
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 530
Realizando operações com strings longas... 1.963

Using mono.exe on Windows:
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 6.875
Realizando operações com strings longas... 6.206
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 6.840
Realizando operações com strings longas... 6.114
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 6.857
Realizando operações com strings longas... 6.116

Using mono on Linux Ubuntu:
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 5,934
Realizando operações com strings longas... 6,915
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 6,034
Realizando operações com strings longas... 7,489
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 5,740
Realizando operações com strings longas... 6,731

Same source code, but on Visual Studio 2008:
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 588
Realizando operações com strings longas... 1.289
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 566
Realizando operações com strings longas... 1.320
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 702
Realizando operações com strings longas... 1.393

VS 2008 generated exe with NGEN (native executable):
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 567
Realizando operações com strings longas... 1.255
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 563
Realizando operações com strings longas... 1.269
Realizando cálculos em 1.000.000 itens... 562
Realizando operações com strings longas... 1.263

In those tests, mono is 10x slower than .net 3.5 SP 1 =(

Comment: Post your benchmark code on mono-devel-list or put a link here so we can see what's up with that code.

Answer (score 2):

C++, C# (Mono), C and Vala: http://jpaflacerda.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/vala-benchmarking/

Many languages: http://attractivechaos.github.com/plb/

Conclusion: Mono evolved alot, but it is still slow when compared with other languages available. I got interested in Vala, which has almost the same syntax of C# but is faster than plain C in some cases.

Comment: Clearly Vala cannot be "faster" than C as it compiles to C an intermediate language. Vala is really just a C code generator. This is not an insult though. I think that Vala is awesome.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It will never be "faster than C", but it might be faster than _usual C_ because it can translate to very well optimized C code and know exactly which flags should be in the compiler to get the best performance (I'm not saying it already does all this, but it might). Also, the benchmark results are there. And yes, Vala is awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the benchmarks are based on heavy computation of tight loops. Time start counting just before the loop and stop just after. If your application is doing heavy data processing then avoid both C# and Java, simply go for C/C++.

It's more likely that your application will be server side. That it will have to accept queries, fetch data and send it back. In such scenario the raw speed of generated code is not relevant compared to other parameters.

You'd better look at how efficient is the underlying framework, how fast is the initialization phase preceding execution of your the code, how easy it is to implement efficient technologies like non blocking I/O, how well is memory released and process recycled after code execution. How easy is it to deploy code, make it scale up...

The human parameter is even more important than all that. A badly written Java is slower than good C# and vice versa. So you have to check your developers. Wich language do they master, wich tool do they like better ? Are they VS/resharper addicts or can they use Java IDE ? The time spend in learning new language or IDE will not be spent on writing better, more optimized code.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen one http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/gp4/csharp.php